# class login100-form-title css not showing

Tags: html, css

```
<body style="background-color: #666666;">
    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <form class="login100-form validate-form" action="<?php echo base_url().'index.php/welcome/login'?>" method="post">
                    <h1 class="login100-form-title fs-70">AWAS</h1>
                    
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-43 fs-20">
                    Accounting Web Application System   
                    </span> 
                    <span class="fs-15">
                        Login to continue
                    </span>
                    
                    <div class="p-t-13 wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid Username is required">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="label-input100">Username</span>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Password is required">
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="password">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="label-input100">Password</span>
                    </div>

                    
                    <div class="warning fs-13" style="color:red;"><span><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('status');?></span></div>
            

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-20">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                

                <div class="login100-more" style="background-image: url('http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/awas/assets/images/bg-01.jpg');">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.login100-form-title {
  width: 1000%;
  display: block;
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
}
```

previously this was normal.

here when i run it

[image: 1]

Nothing happened at all,
I thought it was a problem with xampp, I restarted it and it still has no effect, and I thought it was a problem with my computer, I restarted my computer and still nothing happened.

Comment: Could you please share the styles code too. And please share a working example.

Comment: `.login100-form-title {
  width: 1000%;
  display: block;
  font-family: Poppins-Regular;
  color: #333333;
  line-height: 1.2;
  text-align: center;
}
`

Comment: im sorry but i dont have working example. but if work text "AWAS" it showing

Answer (score 0):

You gave `.login100-form-title` the `width of 1000%` you should make it `100%` and it will work.

Also removing the width completely will solve this problem since `h1` is a `block element` and it will take `100% width` by default.

wrong

```
.login100-form-title {
    width: 1000%;

}
```

Right

```
 .login100-form-title {
        width: 100%;
    
    }
```

[image: result]

That's not what you are looking for? Please let me know and show me more CSS and  I should be able to help.